# How to set value in textbox value after form submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

How to set value in textbox value after form submit?

im using this js block but still im having troubles storing a value in a textbox or div

```
<script type="text/javascript">

(function($,W,D)
{
    var JQUERY4U = {};

    JQUERY4U.UTIL =
    {
        setupFormValidation: function()
        {
            //form validation rules
            $("#register-form").validate({
                rules: {
                    wsndate: "required",
                    wsndescription: "required",
                    wsncrs: "required"},
                messages: {
                    wsndate: "Please enter your wsndate",
                    wsndescription: "Please enter your description",
                    wsncrs: "Please enter a CRS"    
                },
                submitHandler: function(form) {

                    //form.submit();


                    //retrieving form values
                    var wsnString = "";
                    _wsnDate = document.getElementById("wsndate").value;
                    _wsndescription = document.getElementById("wsndescription").value;
                    _wsnCRS = $('select[name="' + $('select[name="dropdownmain"]').val() + '"]').val()


                    //Computation for Page update (simple)
                    _pageupdate_simple = document.getElementById("pageupdate_simple").value;
                    if(document.getElementById("pageupdate_simple_urgent").checked)
                    {
                        //Page update simple URGENT!
                        var _pageupdate_simple_unit_price = 30;
                    }
                        else
                    {
                        //Page update simple Normal
                        var _pageupdate_simple_unit_price = 15;
                    }
                    _pageupdate_simple_cost = _pageupdate_simple * _pageupdate_simple_unit_price;   


                    //Computation for Page update (complex)
                    _pageupdate_complex = document.getElementById("pageupdate_complex").value;
                    if(document.getElementById("pageupdate_complex_urgent").checked)
                    {
                        //Page update complex URGENT!
                        var _pageupdate_complex_unit_price = 50;
                    }
                        else
                    {
                        //Page update complex Normal
                        var _pageupdate_complex_unit_price = 25;
                    }
                    _pageupdate_complex_cost = _pageupdate_complex * _pageupdate_complex_unit_price;    

                    //Computation for PDF update/upload
                    _pdfUpdate = document.getElementById("pdfUpdate").value;

                    var _pdfUpdate_unit_price = 15;
                    var _succeeding_pdf = 7.5;
                    var _pdfNumbers;
                    var _subSequent;
                    var _pdfUpdateCost;

                    if(_pdfUpdate > 1)
                    {
                        _subSequent = _pdfUpdate -1;
                        var _subSequentCost;
                        _subSequentCost = _subSequent * _succeeding_pdf;
                        _pdfUpdateCost = _pdfUpdate_unit_price + _subSequentCost;
                    }
                    else if(_pdfUpdate == 0)
                    {
                        _pdfUpdateCost = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _pdfUpdateCost = _pdfUpdate_unit_price;
                    }

                    //Computation for Add/update promo box
                    _promoboxUpdate = document.getElementById("promoboxUpdate").value;

                    var _promoboxUpdate_unit_price = 15;
                    var _succeeding_promobox = 7.5;
                    var _promoboxNumber;
                    var _subSequentPromobox;
                    var _promoboxUpdateCost;

                    if(_promoboxUpdate > 1)
                    {
                        _subSequentPromobox = _promoboxUpdate -1;
                        var _subSequentPromoboxCost;
                        _subSequentPromoboxCost = _subSequentPromobox * _succeeding_promobox;
                        _promoboxUpdateCost = _promoboxUpdate_unit_price + _subSequentPromoboxCost;
                    }
                    else if(_promoboxUpdate == 0)
                    {
                        _promoboxUpdateCost = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _promoboxUpdateCost = _promoboxUpdate_unit_price;
                    }


                    //Computation for Page Creation
                    _pageCreation = document.getElementById("pageCreation").value;
                    if(document.getElementById("pageCreation_urgent").checked)
                    {
                        //Page creation URGENT!
                        var _pageCreation_unit_price = 100;
                    }
                        else
                    {
                        //Page creation Normal
                        var _pageCreation_unit_price = 50;
                    }
                    _pageCreation_cost = _pageCreation * _pageCreation_unit_price;  

                    //append the values for the costs
                    var _wsnCost = _pageupdate_simple_cost + _pageupdate_complex_cost + _pdfUpdateCost + _promoboxUpdateCost + _pageCreation_cost;



                    wsnString = _wsnDate+'_'+_wsndescription+'_'+_wsnCRS+'_$'+_wsnCost;
                    //Session["wsnvalues"] = wsnString;
                    //window.location.href = 'page2.html';

                    alert(wsnString);


                    //window.location.href = 'page2.html';
                }
            });
        }
    }

    //when the dom has loaded setup form validation rules
    $(D).ready(function($) {
        JQUERY4U.UTIL.setupFormValidation();
    });

})(jQuery, window, document);
</script>
```

i want to set the value of **wsnString** to a textbox or div where i can copy the generated text. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#mytextbox').val(wsnString).
```